# Cannot change TextView between two activities?

Tags: java, android, button, textview

I'm attempting to change a TextView between two activities. The problem is, when I change the text in the other activity from main activity, it works fine, the screen goes to the other activity and the text has been changed. However I have another button which takes me to the other activity from Main, but the newly updated text has disappeared when I press it. Any help?

MyActivity.java

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

        final EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

        b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MyActivity.this, Second.class);
                intent.putExtra("thetext", et.getText().toString());
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.my, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public void onClickGoToActivity(View view) {
        setContentView(R.layout.second);
    }
}
```

Second.java

```
public class Second extends Activity{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.second);

        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        tv.setText(getIntent().getExtras().getString("thetext"));
    }
}
```

activity_my.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MyActivity">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:hint="Change me"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:text="Add text in other activity"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/go_to_activity_button"
        android:text="Go to activity"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
        android:onClick="onClickGoToActivity"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

second.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:textSize="30sp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

AndroidManifest.xml
Second class activity:

I presume the problem lies here:

```
public void onClickGoToActivity(View view) {
            setContentView(R.layout.second);
        }
```

where the newly changed TextView is being reset back to the original layout (where the TextView is empty with no text). I'm not sure how to fix this as I'm new to Android.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

changing content view of activity is a bad idea to start another activity. Simply you just do the same thing which is

```
public void onClickGoToActivity(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MyActivity.this, Second.class);
            intent.putExtra("thetext", et.getText().toString());
            startActivity(intent);
        }
```

Comment: when you say "changing content view of activity is a bad idea to start another activity", are you talking about the "startActivity(intent)" bit? If so, do you mean just get rid of that so the screen doesn't automatically go there once you have pressed "Add text in other activity" button?

Comment: yes exactly. never use setContentView for starting another activity. this only change current view's content view so you can never reach new activity's content view.